# Inconsistent Nan Key Error using Pandas Apply

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm recoding multiple columns in a dataframe and have come across a strange result that I can't quite figure out. I'm probably not recoding in the most efficient manner possible, but it's mostly the error that I'm hoping someone can explain.

```
s1 = pd.DataFrame([np.nan, '1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], columns=['col1'])
s2 = pd.DataFrame([np.nan, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], columns=['col1'])
s1_dic = {np.nan: np.nan, '1': 1, '2':2, '3':3, '4':3, '5':3}
s2_dic = {np.nan: np.nan, 1: 1, 2:2, 3:3, 4:3, 5:3}
s1['col1'].apply(lambda x: s1_dic[x])
s2['col1'].apply(lambda x: s2_dic[x])
```

s1 works fine, but when I try to do the same thing with a list of integers and a np.nan, I get `KeyError: nan` which is confusing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround is to use the get dict method, rather than the lambda:

```
In [11]: s1['col1'].apply(s1_dic.get)
Out[11]:
0   NaN
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     3
5     3
Name: col1, dtype: float64

In [12]: s2['col1'].apply(s2_dic.get)
Out[12]:
0   NaN
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     3
5     3
Name: col1, dtype: float64
```

It's not clear to me right now why this is different...

---

Note: the dicts can be accessed by nan:

```
In [21]: s1_dic[np.nan]
Out[21]: nan

In [22]: s2_dic[np.nan]
Out[22]: nan
```

and `hash(np.nan) == 0` so it's not that...

---

Update: Apparently the issue is with `np.nan` vs `np.float64(np.nan)`, the former has `np.nan is np.nan` (because `np.nan` is bound to a specific instantiated nan object) whilst `float('nan') is not float('nan')`:

This means that get won't find `float('nan')`:

```
In [21]: nans = [float('nan') for _ in range(5)]

In [22]: {f: 1 for f in nans}
Out[22]: {nan: 1, nan: 1, nan: 1, nan: 1, nan: 1}
```

This means you can actually retrieve the nans from a dict, *any such retrieval would be implementation specific!* In fact, as the dict uses the id of these nans, this entire behavior above may be implementation specific (if nan shared the same id, as they may do in a REPL/ipython session).

You can catch the nullness beforehand:

```
In [31]: s2['col1'].apply(lambda x: s2_dic[x] if pd.notnull(x) else x)
Out[31]:
0   NaN
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     3
5     3
Name: col1, dtype: float64
```

But I think the original suggestion of using .get is a better option.

Comment: I think this may be a bug in apply/map_infer, definitely worth a github issue.

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check. I opened an issue on github.

Comment: @DSM Ah yes, I meant is. Thanks!!